# Как в javafx скачать файл с прямой ссылки и сохранить его?

Tags: javafx

Как в javafx скачать файл с прямой ссылки и сохранить его в папку с программой?

Comment: Вариантов много, что уже сделали вы? Или вы хотите, чтобы за вас написали весь код без вашего участия? Не уверен, что это кому - то нужно.

Comment: Я java только начал изучать. До этого писал на C#, там всё в разы проще. Используешь  webClient.DownloadFile и всё. Есть ли аналог в java?

Comment: Просто используете `Files.copy` и все. Раз на то пошло.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроcа: [Java, скачивание фаила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823747/java-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде чем задават вопрос, хотя бы попробуйте поискать ответ.

Несколько различных примеров вы можете найти по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java).

Вот один из них, с использование [Java NIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)):

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/information.asp");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```